# Let $T:V \to V$ be a linear map s.a $T^2=-I$ $(dimV>1)$ Show that for every $v\ne0$, $[v,T(v)]$ are linear independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let V be a vector space above $\mathbb{R}$ and  Let $T:V \to V$ be a linear map s.a $T^2=-I$ $(dimV>1)$

Show that for every $v\ne0$, $[v,T(v)]$ are linear independent.

**My way so far:**

I simply want to prove that $av+bT(v)=0$ has only $a=b=0$ as a solution.

$av+bT(v)=0$ applying the linear map T on both sides yields:

$aT(v)-bv=0$

And I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: What's the base field ?

Comment: you're right, Ive added it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

then $b(av+bT(v))=0$ and $a(T(v)-bv)=0$ sum the both you have $(a^2+b^2)(T(v))=0$ and deduce that $a=b=0$.

Comment: assuming $V$ is a real vector space...